# Discrete probability and approximation to hoeffding inequality

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A sample of heads and tails is created by tossing a coin a number of times independently. Assume we have a number of coins that generate different samples independently. For a given coin, let the probability of heads (probability of error) be $ \mu $. The probability of obtaining $k$ heads in $N$ tosses of this coin is given by the binomial distribution:

$P[k \ | \ N, \mu ] = {{N}\choose{k}} \ \mu^k (1 - \mu)^{N-k}$.

Remember that the training error $v$ is ${\frac{k}{N}}$.

(a) Assume the sample size $(N)$ is 10. If all the coins have $\mu = 0.05$ compute the probability that at least one coin will have $v=0$ for the case of $1$ coin, $1,000$ coins, $1,000,000$ coins. Repeat for $ \mu = 0.8 $

(b) For the case $N = 6$ and $2$ coins with $\mu = 0.5$  for both coins, plot the probability

$P[max_{(i)} \ |v_i - \mu_i| > \epsilon]$

for $\epsilon$ in the range $[0,1]$ (the max is over coins). On the same plot show the bound that would be obtained using the Hoeffding inequality. Remember that for a single coin, the Hoeffding bound is

$P[|v - \mu| > \epsilon] \leq 2e^{-2N \epsilon^2}$.

Hint: Use $P[A or B] = P[A] + P[B] - P[A and B]$

**My Problems with questions here:**

> $a$, I did the calculations and truly when the experiments increase the more probable  rare acases occur. Are they any other thought this question tries to develop or cultıvate in my mind ?
>
> *For Question B, I developed the following solution, please check if my idea is correct or are there any other easier way to solve this, preferably, without detailed case by case analysis***

Let,

> $P(A_1) := |v_1 - 0.5| > |v_2 - 0.5| $ , $v_1$ is max
>
> $P(A_2) := |v_1 - 0.5| > |v_2 - 0.5| $, $v_2$ is max
>
> $P(A_3) := |v_1 - 0.5| = |v_2 - 0.5| $, $v_1 = v_2$

So,

$P(A_1) := P( v_1 > v_2 \ or \ v_1 + v_2 < 1) $

> Let,
>
> $P(V_1):= P(|v_1 - 0.5|) > 0.5$

To compute  $P(V_1)$ we have  either,

$v_1 > \epsilon + 0.5$ or $v_1 < -\epsilon + 0.5$

Now, I do case by case analysis of probability of $v_1$ for the possible values of $\epsilon = \{ 0, 1/3, ... , 1 \}$

> At the end I have the following result from the Bayes theorem,

$P[ \ max_i   \  |v_i - \mu_i| > \epsilon ] \ = \ P(A_1) P(V_1) + P(A_2) P(V_2) + P(A_3) P(V_3)$

**So are there any easy solution for this awkwardly long process of calculation chains ? Can anyone help me with this ?**